# AngularJS: How to trigger function call when a form field gets focus

Tags: angularjs

I want my controller to perform some action when a user clicks in a form field (when the form field gets focus). How can I do this? See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bQUKhn?p=preview).

Here is my controller:
angular.module('myApp', [])

```
.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.field1 = "Default text";
    $scope.focus = false;
    $scope.formFieldJustGotFocus = function() {
      $scope.focus = true; 
      // Do all the stuff I need to happen when the form has just gotten focus
    }
  }
]);
```

And here is the view:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <h3>Testing</h3>
  <p>I want to perform some action in the controller when a form field gets focus. How can I best achieve this?</p>
  <form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="field1" ng-model="field1">
  </form>
  <p>Form field has focus: {{focus}}</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `ngFocus` directive. The inverse is `ngBlur`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  
  <input type="text" ng-focus="isFocused = true" ng-blur="isFocused = false">
  <p ng-if="isFocused">Focus !</p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Lots of correct answers, all given at aprox the same time (I cannot see who was first), so I'll award you @meriadec for having in-answer demo, I had no idea that you could do that here at stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="field1" ng-model="field1" ng-focus="formFieldJustGotFocus()">
```

use like this `ng-focus`

Answer (score 0):

**use -> ng-focus**

```
<input type="text" name="field1" ng-model="field1" ng-focus="formFieldJustGotFocus();">
```

[this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bQUKhn?p=preview)

in the code he had written the function formFieldJustGotFocus(), but it was not bound to the focus event

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solved the problem *by editing your answer.*

Answer (score 0):

Try `ng-focus`.

See more info:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus